# What is wrong with this solution?

Tags: java

Question from some online test:

Cannot copy the question since it is copyrighted. Question can be found here:
http://codility.com/c/run/demo534WQK-UBH

As we can see from the example:

```
P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7
P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5
P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1
P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7
```

sum of elements is always constant (3+10) = (4+9) = (6+7) etc. We also note the number on left side increases while number on right side decreases.

My solution:

```
class Solution
{
    public int solution(int A[])
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            sum += A[i];
        }
        long currSum = 0;
        long ans = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {

            currSum += A[i];
            long diff = Math.abs((sum - currSum) - currSum);
            ans = Math.min(ans, diff);
        }
        return (int) ans;
    }

}
```

http://codility.com/demo/results/demo8MC2GU-7BK/

Now is there any way, I can find out why my solution fails for 2 test cases? I know it may not be possible to see what was the input, so relying on code check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the "P" variable in your answer is ***0 < P <= N***.

But the requirement is ***0 < P < N***.

So you need to change the ***second*** loop from

```
for (int i =0;i<A.length;i++)
```

to

```
for (int i =0;i<A.length-1;i++)
```